# How to reverse an animation on mouse out after hover

Tags: css, animation

So, it is possible to have reverse animation on mouse out such as:

```
.class{
   transform: rotate(0deg);

}
.class:hover{
   transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

but, when using @keyframes animation, I couldn't get it to work, e.g:

```
.class{
   animation-name: out;
   animation-duration:2s;

}
.class:hover{
   animation-name: in;
   animation-duration:5s;
   animation-iteration-count:infinite;

}
@keyframe in{
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframe out{
    to {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

What is the optimal solution, knowing that I'd need iterations and animation itself?

http://jsfiddle.net/khalednabil/eWzBm/

Comment: Would it not be better to use transitions, like here - http://jsfiddle.net/HQFby/ ?

Comment: The answer is already posted on stackoverflow.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38296629/7935298)

Comment: @watereffect that answer is for a different problem.

Answer (score 76):

I think that if you have a `to`, you must use a `from`.
I would think of something like :

```
@keyframe in {
    from: transform: rotate(0deg);
    to: transform: rotate(360deg);
}

@keyframe out {
    from: transform: rotate(360deg);
    to: transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Of course must have checked it already, but I found strange that you only use the `transform` property since CSS3 is not fully implemented everywhere. Maybe it would work better with the following considerations :

- Chrome uses `@-webkit-keyframes`, no particuliar version needed
- Safari uses `@-webkit-keyframes` since version 5+
- Firefox uses `@keyframes` since version 16 (v5-15 used `@-moz-keyframes`)
- Opera uses `@-webkit-keyframes` version 15-22 (only v12 used `@-o-keyframes`)
- Internet Explorer uses `@keyframes` since version 10+

EDIT :

I came up with that fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/JjHNG/35/

Using minimal code. Is it approaching what you were expecting ?

Comment: IE 10 does support keyframe animations.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm using this code just for illustration, I have edited my question and provided a full code to have a look, unfortunately, the from-to didn't work.

Comment: That does revert the transition, but the problem is that if the mouse is out before the end of the hover transition we get this "jump".
After some searching apparently the state of element must be "persisted" so that we can revert from end rotation position, for that "animation-fill-mode: forwards;" can be used, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It would be easier without `keyframes`. Do you absolutely need `keyframes` ?

Comment: Always best to check http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframe for current vendor prefixes.

Comment: @Xaltar When you first load the app, the first animation plays without hovering over the square. Is there anyway to stop that initial load animation from occurring?

Comment: The code in the fiddle is not the same code in the answer here. The code in the fiddle works great.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to the first animation playing on its own after refreshing? Kind of important.

Comment: This answer is ultimately useless if you cannot suppress the animation playing the first time

Comment: If you don't want it to start on page load: add this jQuery script!
 $(".intern").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).addClass("wasHovered");
  });
Then add your out styling on .wasHovered, so it will only play when the link or div has been hovered on at least once.

Comment: Here's an example on how to add jQuery to not have the animation play on page load : https://codepen.io/MateoStabio/pen/jOVvwrM

Comment: Note that you cannot just use the same animation with the 'reverse' flag to animate out. You need a second @keyframes defined going the other direction.

Answer (score 46):

Its much easier than all this:  Simply transition the same property on your element

```
.earth { width:  0.92%;    transition: width 1s;  }
.earth:hover { width: 50%; transition: width 1s;  }
```

https://codepen.io/lafland/pen/MoEaoG

Comment: Yeah, but this will only work if only one property is changed.

Comment: @Marcus `transition: border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;`

Comment: Woah, CSS has come a long way since last time I did some web programming :D

Comment: he is asking about animation !!

Comment: I knew this could be done without keyframes somehow!

Answer (score 28):

I don't think this is achievable using only CSS animations.  I am assuming that CSS transitions **do not** fulfil your use case, because (for example) you want to chain two animations together, use multiple stops, iterations, or in some other way exploit the additional power animations grant you.

I've not found any way to trigger a CSS animation specifically on mouse-out without using JavaScript to attach "over" and "out" classes. Although you can use the base CSS declaration trigger an animation when the :hover ends, that same animation will then run on page load.  Using "over" and "out" classes you can split the definition into the base (load) declaration and the two animation-trigger declarations.

The CSS for this solution would be:

```
.class {
    /* base element declaration */
}
.class.out {
   animation-name: out;
   animation-duration:2s;

}
.class.over {
   animation-name: in;
   animation-duration:5s;
   animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@keyframes in {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes out {
    from {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

And using JavaScript (jQuery syntax) to bind the classes to the events:

```
$(".class").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 18):

Creating a reversed animation is kind of overkill to a simple problem. What you need is:

```
animation-direction: reverse
```

However, this won't work on its own because animation spec forgot to add a way to restart the animation, so here is how you do it with the help of JS

```js
let item = document.querySelector('.item')

// play normal
item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  item.classList.add('active')
})

// play in reverse
item.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  item.style.opacity = 0 // avoid showing the init style while switching the 'active' class

  item.classList.add('in-active')
  item.classList.remove('active')

  // force dom update
  setTimeout(() => {
    item.classList.add('active')
    item.style.opacity = ''
  }, 5)

  item.addEventListener('animationend', onanimationend)
})

function onanimationend() {
  item.classList.remove('active', 'in-active')
  item.removeEventListener('animationend', onanimationend)
}
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

div {
  background: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  /* because span cant be animated */
  display: block;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.item.active {
  animation: spin 1s forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.item.in-active {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="item">ABC</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

we can use requestAnimationFrame to reset animation and reverse it when browser paints in next frame.

Also use onmouseenter and onmouseout event handlers to reverse animation direction

[As per](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4)

> Any rAFs queued in your event handlers will be executed in the ​same
>   frame​. Any rAFs queued in a rAF will be executed in the next frame​.

```js
function fn(el, isEnter) {
  el.className = "";
   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        el.className = isEnter? "in": "out";
    });
  });  
}
```

```css
.in{
  animation: k 1s forwards;
}

.out{
  animation: k 1s forwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes k
{
from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
to   {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red" 
  onmouseenter="fn(this, true)"
   onmouseleave="fn(this, false)"  
     ></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Would you be better off having just the one animation, but having it reverse?

```
animation-direction: reverse
```

Comment: Currently only supported in [some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)

Comment: Have any example ?

Answer (score 3):

Using transform in combination with transition works flawlessly for me:

```
.ani-grow {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}
.ani-grow:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a CodePen with a CSS-only fix and one with 2 lines of jQuery to fix the on-page load issue. Continue reading to understand the 2 solutions in a simpler version.

https://codepen.io/MateoStabio/pen/jOVvwrM

If you are searching how to do this with CSS only, Xaltar's answer is simple, straightforward, and is the correct solution. The only downside is that the animation for the mouse out will play when the page loads. This happens because to make this work, you style your element with the OUT animation and the `:hover` with the IN animation.

```
svg path{
    animation: animateLogoOut 1s;
}
svg:hover path{
    animation: animateLogoIn 1s;
}

@keyframes animateLogoIn {
    from {stroke-dashoffset: -510px;}
    to {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
}
@keyframes animateLogoOut {
    from {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
    to {stroke-dashoffset: -510px;}
}
```

Some people found this solution to be useless as it played on page load. For me, this was the perfect solution. But I made a Codepen with both solutions as I will probably need them in the near future.

If you do not want the CSS animation on page load, you will need to use a tiny little script of JS that styles the element with the OUT animation only after the element has been hovered for the first time. We will do this by adding a class of `.wasHovered` to the element and style the added class with the OUT Animation.

jQuery:

```
$("svg").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).addClass("wasHovered");
 });
```

CSS:

```
svg path{

}

svg.wasHovered path{
    animation: animateLogoOut 1s;
}

svg:hover path{
    animation: animateLogoIn 1s;
}

@keyframes animateLogoIn {
    from {stroke-dashoffset: -510px;}
    to {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
}
@keyframes animateLogoOut {
    from {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
    to {stroke-dashoffset: -510px;}
}
```

And voila! You can find all of this and more on my codepen showing in detail the 2 options with an SVG logo hover animation.

https://codepen.io/MateoStabio/pen/jOVvwrM

Answer (score 2):

*[OP is asking about `animation` specifically here, but if all you need is to initiate and reverse `rotate` based on hover state without a specific `animation-iteration-count` (though you could possibly calculate the degrees to mimic it), you can use the below.]*

As of May 2023, we can accomplish this with just an [individual `transform`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms) (relevant [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_rotate)) and a `transition`.

```
.box {
  rotate: 0deg;
  transition: rotate 2s;
}

.box:hover {
  rotate: 360deg;
}
```

Some things to note:

- Mobile implementation for individual `transform`s is very new (as recent as two weeks before this post), so for full support, either fall back to the original syntax or use LightningCSS/Autoprefixer

View an example below or [on Codepen](https://codepen.io/mandynicole/pen/XWxyreq):

```css
.box {
  transition: rotate 2s;
  rotate: 0deg;
}
.box:hover {
  rotate: 360deg;
}

.box:nth-of-type(5):hover {
  rotate: 1080deg;
}


/* visuals (ignore) */
.box {
  --d: 90px;
  height: var(--d);
  width: var(--d);
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have tried several solutions here, nothing worked flawlessly; then Searched the web a bit more, to find **GSAP** at https://greensock.com/ (subject to license, but it's pretty permissive); once you reference the lib ...

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

... you can go:

```
  var el = document.getElementById('divID');    

  // create a timeline for this element in paused state
  var tl = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

  // create your tween of the timeline in a variable
  tl
  .set(el,{willChange:"transform"})
  .to(el, 1, {transform:"rotate(60deg)", ease:Power1.easeInOut});

  // store the tween timeline in the javascript DOM node
  el.animation = tl;

  //create the event handler
  $(el).on("mouseenter",function(){
    //this.style.willChange = 'transform';
    this.animation.play();
  }).on("mouseleave",function(){
     //this.style.willChange = 'auto';
    this.animation.reverse();
  });
```

And it will work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@keyframe in {
from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframe out {
from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

supported in Firefox 5+, IE 10+, Chrome, Safari 4+, Opera 12+

Answer (score 0):

If you have different `transition`for the element and the hover element you can achieve this.

In this example there are two different @keyframes, one for onMouseOver and one for onMouseOut.
One is for `.shimmer`. The other one is for `.shimmer:hover` (`.button:hover .shimmer` in this example).

Then we have two different `transition:` for `.shimmer`and `.shimmer:hover` (`.button:hover .shimmer` in this example).

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #61a204;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

.shimmer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%; 
  left: 100%; 
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  filter: blur(20px);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  animation: shine-out .3s linear 1 alternate;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease 1s;
}

.button:hover .shimmer { 
  left: 0; 
  right: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  animation: shine-in .4s linear 1 alternate;  
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s ease 0s;
}

.button:hover  {
    background-color: #61a204;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    color: #fff;
}

@keyframes shine-in {
  50% { transform: rotate(35deg);  left: 50%; }
  100% { transform: rotate(35deg);  left: 100%; }
}
@keyframes shine-out {
  50% { transform: rotate(-35deg);  left: 50%; }
  100% { transform: rotate(-35deg);  left: 0; }
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
    <div class="shimmer"></div>
    My Text
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a little surprised that this purely CSS solution worked:
But it does !!

```
.mySelector:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 0.5s transform ease-in-out;
}

.mySelector:not(:hover) {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: 0.5s transform ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a relatively new solution to the OP's question, made possible by the introduction of the :not() pseudo-selector.