# Reverse a spritesheet animation on mouse out

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am trying to animate a logo with spritesheet ans it is working pretty well.
The code is like

```
#logo {
  background: url('../img/logo.png');
  height: 142px;
  width: 426px;
}
#logo:hover{
  -webkit-animation: logoAnim .2s steps(19) forwards; 
} 
@-webkit-keyframes logoAnim { 
    100% { background-position: -8094px 0; }
}
```

So the image is animating on mouse hover. Now I am clueless how to reverse the animation on mouse out. Can someone help me pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3: reverse animation on mouse out after hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/css3-reverse-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect very easily using jquery like this:

```
$('#logo').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css("background-position","-8094px 0");
});

$('#logo').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css("background-position","0 0");
});
```

and you can include the following Css to `#logo` according to your needs:

```
#logo {
  -webkit-transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Nice thought.. However this will animate the sprite by just moving it it.. We are missing the steps here

Answer (score 0):

This trick is made by [animation-direction](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-direction.asp).

Example:

```
-webkit-animation: logoAnim 1s alternate-reverse;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XuSXK/

Comment: The mouse out is not reversing in this fiddle