# reverse svg animation when hover is over?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, css-transitions

I simply want my svg lines to reverse their animation after the user stops hovering over the parent div switch executes it.

There is a fair amount of code so I just made a jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/tiwejekicu/2/edit

So my question is: how do I get it to act like any old transition and reverse itself when the hover is over. ALSO: how come when the yellow box is clicked a blue fade comes from the left edge? Any ideas?! Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two @keyframe rules:

```
@keyframe in {
from {something;}
to {to something;}
}
@keyframe out {
from {something;}
to {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/css3-reverse-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover) it's basically the same.

Comment: Please show how this would work with the asker's current code.