# Hover off animation?

Tags: html, css, hover

How do I do the inverse animation when I "hover off" the  `.child` element (css3 only if possible)?

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z53n84v/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="child">
    <i class="fa fa-video-camera spin" style="font-size:22px;"></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child:hover .spin{
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.2s linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 0.2s linear;
    -o-animation: spin 0.2s linear;
     animation: spin 0.2s linear;        
}
    
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
    
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }    
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/css3-reverse-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `transition` instead of `keyframes`:

```css
.child .spin {
    transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.child:hover .spin{
     transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="child">
    <i class="fa fa-video-camera spin" style="font-size:22px;"></i>
</div>
```

Comes with auto-reverse built in. Much less code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use animation, use transition

```
<div class="camera"></div>
<style>
.camera{
height: 100px;
width: 50px;
background-color: red;
transition: 2s;
}
.camera:hover{
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
</style>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofh0bnup/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do that. But you'll need a default animation too.

```css
.child{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.child .spin{
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: spin 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: spin 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: spin 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.child:hover .spin{
  -webkit-animation: spinh 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: spinh 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: spinh 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: spinh 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinh {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinh {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
  <i class="fa fa-video-camera spin" style="font-size:22px;"></i>
</div>
```

[See the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3z53n84v/2/).