# Is there a CSS-only (pure CSS) workaround to apply fade-in and fade-out on objects with display:none?

Tags: css

I know the effect can be easily achieved with jQuery `hide()`. The goal here is to do it with pure CSS instead. The fade-out result must <s>have `display:none` so the element</s> takes up zero space on the page layout (so `visibility:hidden` isn't an option).

I got success on made a fade-in effect with pure CSS on the `display:none` object using a piece of `animation` instead of `transition`, but I couldn't make it work on fade-out without to use the javascript `setTimeout` method.

Here's what I got so far:

```js
function aaa(){
document.getElementById("b").style.display = "inline-block";  
}

function bbb(){
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("b").style.display = "none"; }, 1000);   
}
```

```css
#b {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
  background: skyblue;
}

#a:hover ~ #b {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: animate 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: animate 1s;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

div {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a {
  background: tomato;  
}

#c {
  background: greenyellow;  
}
```

```html
<div id=a onmouseenter="aaa()" onmouseleave="bbb()">OVER</div>
<div id=b>B</div>
<div id=c>C</div>
```

**Is it possible to reach this same result using zero javascript?**

[**codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/mPwPax)

Comment: You can't animate with `display: none` using CSS only. Why not use height?

Comment: `height:0`; only works for empty divs, no?

Comment: You are wrong, I made a test, the content floats outside of it instead of disappear together with the div; [**screenshot**](https://i.gyazo.com/148ca47b4fc9d72e37e7f539c13e34e8.png)

Comment: You need `overflow: hidden`

Comment: This is great I didn't know about this possibility;

Comment: Posted an answer for you

Comment: thank you very much; I'm playing with it on codepen trying to put it together with the fade effect;

Comment: Made a 2:nd sample in my answer using max-height in case height: auto is required

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I post an improved (in the way of cover the OP) version of your answer?

Comment: Absolute not .. if it is better than mine I might borrow yours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [**LGSon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) presented on the comments (and later on an answer), an alternative to `display:none` is `height:0` combined with `overflow:hidden`.

So I did use this method together with opacity values on keyframes/transition to reproduce the fade-in/fade-out effects of the OP snippet, but without any javascript.

`transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier` was used to perform a quick jump to `height:0`

```css
#b {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, height 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,1,0); /* Safari */
  transition: opacity 1s, height 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,1,0);
  background: skyblue;
}

#a:hover ~ #b {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: animate 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: animate 1s;
  height: 60px;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%   {opacity: 0;
  height: 60px;}
    100% { opacity: 1;
  height: 60px;}
}

div {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;  
}

#a {
  background: tomato;  
}

#c {
  background: greenyellow;  
}
```

```html
<div id=a>OVER</div>
<div id=b>B</div>
<div id=c>C</div>
```

Comment: Here is a few tricks to avoid it from running on load: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938900/how-to-prevent-css-keyframe-animation-to-run-on-page-load

Comment: @LGSon Updated with info from your link (use transition instead of keyframes to avoid the play on page load) combined with `transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier` and now it is just perfect. Thank you very much, this answer is half yours.

Comment: handy tool used to quick find the bezier numbers: [**link**](http://cubic-bezier.com/)

Answer (score 9):

As you can't animate `display: none` with CSS only, here is an alternative using `height`

```css
#b {
  height:0;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: skyblue;
}

#a:hover ~ #b {
  height: 58px;
}

div {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a {
  background: tomato;  
}

#c {
  background: greenyellow;  
}
```

```html
<div id=a>OVER</div>
<div id=b>B</div>
<div id=c>C</div>
```

If you need `height: auto`, you can use `max-height` like this

```css
#b {
  max-height:0;
  padding: 0px 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: skyblue;
}

#a:hover ~ #b {
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

div {
  width: 58px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#a {
  background: tomato;  
}

#c {
  background: greenyellow;  
}
```

```html
<div id=a>OVER</div>
<div id=b>B</div>
<div id=c>C</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is 'no'. You can use opacity to animate fade in/out using css only, but changing display has no transition.

If your div contains only text, you may be able to do this using font-size.

If there are inner divs or images with specific dimensions, you will need to explicitly cater for these by transitioning their width/height within the div being hidden, bit that means knowing what is in the html when creating your css.