# Not play animation first time after page load CSS

Tags: css, animation

Good day to all
Is there a way to not play animation after page load? **Without JS and CSS transition**.
Searched here and couldn't find an answer.
I sketched a small example where you can clearly see this problem. See code below.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  animation: fadeOut forwards alternate .8s;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

button:hover .tooltip {
  animation: fadeIn forwards alternate .8s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  99% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span>text</span>
    <span class="tooltip"><a href="#">press my</a></span>
</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, this stackoverflow question might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938900/how-to-prevent-a-css-keyframe-animation-from-running-on-page-load

Comment: you can achieve similar effect using `transition` without `animation`

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no answer. Options either with JS or transition ((

Comment: transition  can't change property display: block;

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML?