# Grow circular image using keyframes and CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm trying to grow a circular image on hover, but can't get this code to work.

I can get the circle to grow using the CSS transform but it grows immediately and is a bit ugly. Ideally I'd want there to be a 2-3000ms delay with linear growth both on hover and mouse out.

I know I can do this with JS/D3 but need to do it with CSS if possible.

Have tried

```
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper.vc_box_circle:hover
{

animation: mymove 3s normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        0%
        {
        width:250px;}

    25%
    {
    width:260px;}

    75%
    {
    width:270px;}

    100%
    {
    width:280px;
    }
}
```

and

```
 .wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper.vc_box_circle:hover
{
animation: mymove 3s normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        0%
        {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);}
         }
        25%
        {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.033);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.033);
        transform: scale(1.033);}

        75%
        {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.066);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.066);
        transform: scale(1.066);}

        100%
        {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        }
```

But neither are working.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use [**animation-delay**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)

Comment: And `transition-timing-function: linear;` if I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

[I've created a pen based on your code](http://codepen.io/suth_a/pen/BNLdgb)

Using `transform: scale` is a better method since it increases both `width` and `height`.

The key thing you missed out on for creating a smooth animation is the transition attribute, this needs to be applied to the element in it's normal state not it's `:hover` state.

I've added this transition styling:

```
transition: 3s ease-in-out;
```

Note that it's the same length as your animation timing. `ease-in-out` is a standard easing function, if you'd like to get more in-depth try playing around with [cubic-bezier](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67)

Animation delay can be added easily with this attribute:

```
animation-delay:2s
```

Another thing which makes keyframe animations smoother is having the 0% and 100% stylings the same, so in this example the circle returns to the original scale by the time it reaches 100% which creates a nice, smooth, repeatable animation.

[I've also created an alternative animation](http://codepen.io/suth_a/pen/WvGZve) which looks even smoother, this is done by simply setting scale for the 0% and 100% points in the animation:

```
0%{transform: scale(1)}
100%{transform: scale(2)}
```

Another thing you can do is change your animation loop setting from `normal` to `infinite alternate`, checkout my second example this is using `infinite alternate` which makes the circle grow and shrink with no sudden snaps.

Comment: are you using Chrome? I've missed out the browser prefixes, also with regards to reversing the animation on mousleave this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/css3-reverse-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover

Comment: I've added vendor prefixes to my second example now

Comment: Actually still not working for me even with the vendor prefixes. I'm using Chrome

Comment: what both demos? there is a 2 second delay as requested so you need to hover for 2 seconds before the animation starts

Comment: Yeah both demos. I thought it might be because I have a touchscreen (which turns :hover into a click event), but it doesn't work on non-touchscreen laptop also.

Comment: so you're seeing no animation at all?

Comment: No nothing at all, just a 250X250 red circle

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the start of an animation with `animation-delay`

Such as

```
.delay {
     animation-delay:2s
}
```

[**Reference @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)

Demo showing the difference below

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
}
.circle:hover {
  animation: mymove 3s normal;
}
.delay:hover {
  animation-delay: 2s
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
25% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.033);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.033);
  transform: scale(1.033);
}
75% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.066);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.066);
  transform: scale(1.066);
}
100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.033);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.033);
    transform: scale(1.033);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.066);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.066);
    transform: scale(1.066);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" alt="" class="circle" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" alt="" class="circle delay" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the start of the transition by using the transition-delay property.

```
div {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp)