# Keyframe CSS animation overwrites hover transition

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, keyframe

I am afraid there are similar questions to this but I didn’t found a concrete solution, so I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Garavani/yrnjaf69/2/

```
<div class= "category_item">

    <div class= "cat_button">
        <span class="title_cat">TEXT</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.category_item {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #999;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    /* seems to be overwriten by animation keyframes */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.215s ease-in-out;
            transition: transform 0.215s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.category_item:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: easeBack;
            animation-name: easeBack;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes easeBack {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
                transform: translateY(-50px);

    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
                transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
}   

.cat_button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.215s ease-in-out, border 0.215s ease-in-out, color 0.215s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.215s ease-in-out, border 0.215s ease-in-out, color 0.215s ease-in-out;
}

.category_item:hover .cat_button {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #511c5b;
}
```

In this (simplified) animation everything works fine except for when the mouse leaves the entire box. The animation starts from it original state, but abruptly.
The basic transition time (and ease) is ignored because it seems the keyframes have higher importance and overwrite it.

What I need is the keyframe animation triggering AND when the mouse leaves it should turn back to the original state smoothly.

Is there a solution for this
1) in pure CSS
2) maybe with some little javascript only?

Thanks in advance for help and ideas!

**EDIT:**

After implementing the solution offered kindly by Toni this is the correct fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yrnjaf69/40/

Thanks again Toni!

**EDIT 2:**

Sadly, yet, there is one question left. The part with the keyframes is not executed on Firefox even though I added all the -moz- vendors, too, in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dr6Ld0wL/1/

Why?

PS: As far as I tested for now it works even in Opera (Beta). Only browser resisting is Firefox

**EDIT 3:**
The correct (working) code is now in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dr6Ld0wL/16/

The keyframes also need to be explicitly divided in vendor prefixes. Jesus Christ. Those prefixes…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrnjaf69/31/) that achieves this.

```
.demo-hover {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
    animation: complexProcessReversed 2s ease-in forwards;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #88d;
}
.demo-hover:hover {
    animation: complexProcess 2s ease-in forwards;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #732;
}

@keyframes complexProcess {
    /* keyframes */
}

@keyframes complexProcessReversed {
    /* keyframes (opposite) */
}
```

The animation out is assigned in the css in the main class, then the hover state kicks in on hover and css re-applies the original class properties on unhover.

The animation does trigger backwards on page load, so you might like to think of tweaking your animation to take this into account, like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JjHNG/35/), pinched from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516826/1249829). Alternatively, use javascript (or jquery), like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yrnjaf69/25/) where the animations are triggered by adding and removing classes to the target using jquery:

JavaScript

```
$('.demo-hover').hover(
    function() {
        // mouse in
        $(this).removeClass('forwards--reversed').addClass('forwards');
    },    
    function() {
        // mouse out
        $(this).removeClass('forwards').addClass('forwards--reversed');
    }
);
```

CSS

```
.forwards {
    animation: complexProcess 2s ease-in forwards;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #732;
}

.forwards--reversed {
    animation: complexProcessReversed 2s ease-in forwards;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #88d;
}
```

Also, I'd use `@keyframe` **or** `transition`. Use `transition` if you just need a simple even change from *n* to *m* but when things are more complex, such as one thing changing evenly over 100% but another thing not starting until 50% off the animation has played, then use a `@keyframe`

Using both will cause confusion, especially if you're trying to animate the same properties.

Finally **css vendor prefixes are required**

Comment: Thanks man, I will take a closer look to this tomorrow morning with a good cup (or2) of espresso. At the moment the fiddles look quite nervous ;-) I will have to dive into your logic with a fresh mind.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn’t succeed to bring your example code close to the direction of my fiddle in any way. Your fiddle switches from a brown rectangle to a violet without any transition ? :-( Thanks nevertheless for your willing to help me.

Comment: @Garavani - it's supposed to serve as a demonstration of how to apply a keyframe on and a keyframe off based on hover (as you ask: 'What I need is the keyframe animation triggering AND when the mouse leaves it should turn back to the original state smoothly?') - the keyframe contents are up to you :-)

Comment: also, I added a bit extra, I think use one or the other, with transitions for very simple animations and keyframes for everything else

Comment: So you solved my problem! Thanks I was a bit confused because omitting the vendor on my Safari browser nothing was animated ;-)

Comment: Hi Toni, if you have some patience left, see my edit! :-)

Comment: @Garavani - sorry about that! Yes, prefixes are required, I try to keep my answers as clean as possible code-wise, but I should have mentioned prefixes

Comment: You are doing fine. My fault. But what do you say regarding the Firefox problem?

Comment: Maybe if anyone is interested, I did another EDIT (3) with working CSS for all browsers webkit and Firefox, Opera.