# CSS transform rotate back

Tags: css

I have found this snippet: [codepen.io/gianmichelle/pen/xpwEh/](http://codepen.io/gianmichelle/pen/xpwEh/)
Givs a chance, that the icon is rotate back when i go away with my mouse?
On hover i rotate 360°. But I don't found a way to rotate back on mouse left.

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.me {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}
.me p,
.me h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.me p {
  font-weight: 200;
}
.me span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.social {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
.social ul {
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-270px, 0);
  transform: translate(-270px, 0);
}
.social ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.social ul li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(110px, 0);
  transform: translate(110px, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.social ul li:hover a {
  color: #000;
}
.social ul li:hover i {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.social ul li i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
body {
  background: #25343F;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/gian_michelle">Twitter <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://facebook.com/gian.michelle">Facebook <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://dribbble.com/gian_michelle">Dribbble <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://behance.net">Behance <i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="me">
  <p>Created by:
    <p>
      <h1>Gian Di Serafino</h1>
      <p>for <span>Informartion architecture</span>
      </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/css3-reverse-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add transition to `.social ul li i` element not to `.social ul li:hover i` element, because in your example, transition is only active, when you hover over element. And you want transition to be active all time.

You have to add:

```
.social ul li i {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;    
}
```

Here is pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgVXwN

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add initial rotate code to i element;

```
  .social ul li i {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
```