# CSS animation: hover-in and hover-out

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, css-transitions

I tried to make an animation that is triggered on hover and hover out.
I didn't use the transition property because the animations are quite complex.

- on hover in: zoom-in the element from 100% => 150% => 130%
- on hover out: zoom-out the element from 130% => 80% => 100%

The hover-in works perfectly, but the hover-out always running at startup.
It should animate when has been hover-in.

Then tried to set the CSS var `--anim-hover-out: none`, so no animation on startup. Then, on the end of hover-in, set `--anim-hover-out: hover-out`, so the hover-out animation now ready to play. But setting the CSS var inside `@keyframes` didn't work.

The goal is: `.test:not(:hover):has-hover { do hover-out animation }`

Note: no JavaScript, pure CSS only.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

div {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}
:root {
  --anim-hover-out: unset;
}

.test:not(:hover) {
  animation-name: var(--anim-hover-out);
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.test:hover {
  animation-name: hover-in;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes hover-in {
  0: {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    --anim-hover-out: hover-out;
  }
}
@keyframes hover-out {
  0: {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse an animation on mouse out after hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516793/how-to-reverse-an-animation-on-mouse-out-after-hover)

Answer (score 4):

**There is no way to set this without using JavaScript.**

Because even if you manually define the animation name, the animation is triggered instantly.

- So setting it up afterwards is not a solution. After the important (`onmouseleave`) thing you have to set it over.

**See also snippet**

A complete example that works

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

div {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}
:root {
  --anim-hover-out: hover-out-fake;
}

.test:hover {
  animation-name: hover-in;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.test {
  animation-name: var(--anim-hover-out);
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes hover-in {
  0: {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    --anim-hover-out: hover-out;
  }
}
@keyframes hover-out {
  0: {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test" onmouseleave="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--anim-hover-out', 'hover-out')">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Actually this can be achieved with CSS-only. Admittedly it is a hacky way to do it, but if Javascript is out of the question for some reason, then we can add an animation to a wrapper that will change its opacity from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your content for the initial phases of page load via

```
body{
    animation-name: loading;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

which will hide your item while it's performing the hover-out animation at page initialization. If you want to avoid waiting, then you can attach the animations to classes, like `.hovered` and `.blurred` and toggle them via Javascript. If hiding `body` for one of its elements is too much, then you can wrap another div around your div and specify this animation for that one.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

div {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}
:root {
  --anim-hover-out: unset;
}

body{
    animation-name: loading;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.test:not(:hover) {
  animation-name: hover-out;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.test:hover {
  animation-name: hover-in;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes hover-in {
  0: {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    --anim-hover-out: hover-out;
  }
}
@keyframes hover-out {
  0: {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Hello World!</div>
```