# mouse away from elements to slowly revert back to their original positions [ CSS animation ]

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, css-transitions

**What I have**
I have 1 parent div containing 2 div's of bg-color green and orange, I animated so that when I hover over them they get bg-color red for duration 1s, for now everything works fine.

**what I need**
When I hover, it nicely animates for 1s, but when I move mouse from div's it immediately comes to original styles, but I need them to take 2s to revert back to original styles when  I move mouse away from that elements

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height: 100vh;
}

.fst--row {
    width: 80rem;
    height: 20rem;

    display: flex;
    gap: 0.7rem;
}

.fst--row>div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fst--row>div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #099268;
}

.fst--row>div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #e67700;
}

.fst--row>div:hover {
    animation: hover--flex 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes hover--flex {

    to {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexLaying.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fst--row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do this with pure HTML/CSS animations. However, you have some options!

Firstly, if it's just one property, you should consider the [CSS transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition). You can set it on the element to change as `transition: 1s background-color;`, then specify the intended `:hover` style (e.g. `background-color: blue;`) as you normally would. CSS magic handles the rest :)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height: 100vh;
}

.fst--row {
    width: 80rem;
    height: 20rem;

    display: flex;
    gap: 0.7rem;
}

.fst--row>div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 1s background-color;
}

.fst--row>div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #099268;
}

.fst--row>div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #e67700;
}

.fst--row>div:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexLaying.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fst--row">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you can use javascript to toggle classes (Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626510/8273686), and trigger your animations that way.

```js
$("#box1").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('mouseleave').addClass('mouseover');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('mouseover').addClass('mouseleave');
    }
);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height: 100vh;
}

.fst--row {
    width: 80rem;
    height: 20rem;

    display: flex;
    gap: 0.7rem;
}

.fst--row>div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 1s background-color;
}

.fst--row>div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #099268;
}

.fst--row>div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #e67700;
}


.mouseover {
  animation: mouseover 1s forwards;
}

.mouseleave {
  animation: mouseleave 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes mouseover {
    from {
      background-color: #099268;
    }
    to {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@keyframes mouseleave {
    from {
      background-color: red;
    }
    to {
        background-color: #099268;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexLaying.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fst--row">
        <div id="box1"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```